# Change colors of the rules in minitoc

Tags: color, rules, minitoc

I'm deseperatly trying to change the colors of the rules in minitoc.

I tried differents things :

Try 1 : Change all hrule colors with

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{blue}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
```

Result : Only change the end rule of minitoc. May be the first one is not a hrule.

**EDIT :**
Try 2 : Disable rules and draw by myself

Result : It works but the rules are very bad handled and the vertical spacing is random... 
I managed to do this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\vspace{-25pt}}
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-35pt}}

\dominitoc
%\tableofcontents

\chapter{My Chapter}
{\large \bfseries \textcolor{red}{Sommaire}}
\noindent \textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\minitoc
\noindent \textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And I would like to remove space between the line "Sommaire" and the first rule. Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post your desired output and a compilable code example (instead of or in addition to the fragments)?

Comment: Are you sure that your code produces two rules? For me there's only one rule (after adding the `xcolor` package and changing the color to a color which is predefined).

Comment: Yeah i'm pretty sure. I disabled the minitoc rules with `\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}` and replace the title by a top rule `\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{\textcolor{primary_shade3}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}` and added after the minitoc the end rule with `\noindent \textcolor{primary_shade3}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}`

Comment: Please, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Your MWE does not compile.

Comment: I edited my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not compile your MWE as necessary packages and commands were missing.

The two lines are differently set. The top rule can be colourd using `\arrayrulecolor{red}`, for the bottom rule the definition can be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
\def\mtc@bottom@rule{%
  \ifx\mtc@rule\relax\relax\else
      \vskip -2.5ex
        \color{red}\rule[2.4\p@]{\columnwidth}{.4\p@}\vspace*{2.6\p@}\fi}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents
\dominitoc

\chapter{Chapter}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\minitoc

\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working ! Thanks ! Do you know how to set the exact same vertical space between the top rule and the content and the bottom rule and the content ? Best !

Comment: @Maxouille That is a new question.

Comment: New question here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434264/same-space-between-top-and-bottom-rule-minitoc

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Please I need help with the color of my glossaries in my text. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683022/personalize-the-color-of-the-references-glossary-citation-figure-and-equation. I have customized the colors of \ref, \eqref and \cite however for the glossaries mentioned in test as \textcolor{blue}{\gls{k}} they are displayed in linkcolor...

Comment: @Wallflower I'm a bit confused why you pinged me here? I don't see the connection between this answer and your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it's seems weird, but I used your answer here in my report, and because I did not get an answer in my post I thought maybe I can ask for help here by redirecting you to my question