# Same space between top and bottom rule minitoc

Tags: rules, minitoc, vspace

I want to have the exact same space between the top and bottom rule of minitoc.
I know I can use :

```
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\vspace{-10pt}}
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-10pt}}
```

However the space is fixed and appears to be different in the top and the bottom.

How can I do to have the exact same space between the rules and the content of the minitoc ?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
\def\mtc@bottom@rule{%
  \ifx\mtc@rule\relax\relax\else
      \vskip -2.5ex
        \color{red}\rule[2.4\p@]{\columnwidth}{.4\p@}\vspace*{2.6\p@}\fi}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents
\dominitoc

\chapter{Chapter}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\minitoc

\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Best

Comment: What should happen if your last entry in the minitoc has deceners, e.g. `g`, `j` etc?

Comment: I don't get it ...

Comment: Should the space be bigger in that case or not?

Comment: Oh, yeah definitely