# How to change the width of minitoc rule

Tags: rules, width, minitoc

I want to change the width of my minitoc rule as it exceeds my page margin.
I found this [Change colors of the rules in minitoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431087/change-colors-of-the-rules-in-minitoc) and this can be used to change the bottom rule. But how to change the top one? Or nicer both in one?

```
\def\mtc@top@rule{%
  \ifx\mtc@rule\relax\relax\else
      \vskip -2.5ex
        \rule[2.4\p@]{0.9\columnwidth}{.4\p@}\vspace*{2.6\p@}\fi}
```

doesnt work, neither does:

```
\def\mtc@rule{\rule[2.4\p@]{0.9\columnwidth}{.4\p@}\vspace*{2.6\p@}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,dvipsnames]{scrbook} 
\KOMAoptions{
paper           = A4,               % setze das Papierformat
fontsize        = 12pt,             % setze die Schriftgröße
parskip         = full,             % deFfiniert den Abstand und das Einrücken eines neuen Paragraphen
twoside         = true,             % stelle auf zweiseitiges Dokument
listof          = totoc,            % Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
bibliography    = totoc,            % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
headsepline     = true,
%   footsepline     = true,
overfullrule    = true,             % sollte eine Zeile über den Rand hinausgehen, so wird da mit einem schwarzen Rechteck hervorgehoben
titlepage       = firstiscover,     % Die Titelseit erhält ein anderes Layout als das restliche Dokument.
chapterprefix   = true,
}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcsetrules{minitoc}{on}  

\begin{document}
    \dominitoc
    \chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}
    \minitoc%
    \section{Conclusion}
    \section{Outlook}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried a lot of different things but nothing that works nice.. Can anyone help with how to redefine the top rule?

Comment: My solution now is to scale all '\columnwidth' in minitoc.sty